# A suitable device or software for taking note in class when there are many mathematical formulas.

Tags: soft-question

I will do a mathematical degree. and I need take note in class. But I do not want to use the paper to take note.

Any suggestions? I need to write a lot of mathematical formations alongside text many characters.

Comment: To my opinion, nothing is better than pen and paper when it comes to taking notes in math course. I am at a graduate level in mathematics, and I never met anyone using anything else before. That being said, if you really do not want to use paper, I would recommend a graphic tablet on which you can directly write. This way, you won't loose time when copying lines and lines of equations.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. You mean I can use the graphic tablet to draw and write the equations. Could I use it to text the characters?

Comment: If you can type fast then you can directly take notes in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Tips for taking notes in LaTeX: https://www.google.com/search?q=live+latex+note+taking

Comment: You can try [LyX](http://www.lyx.org), which is a nearly WYSIWYG LaTeX editor. But it may not be as fast as pen[cil] and paper.

Answer (score 1):

As @Suzet pointed out, nothing is better than a pen and a paper in a maths class. However, you may wish to give a try to Wolfram Alpha to quickly type out mathematical equations. It will also try to solve the entered equations for you, and you need to check how to disable that if not required.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pen and paper as I found that that's the best way to remember the content well. However otherwise I suggest you buy a tablet (e.g. iPad Pro) which is designed for you to take notes on.